# Text alignment title page

Tags: minipage

A simple question here, since I coulnd't find anything that addresses it specifically. I probably missed it somewhere, but I only get hits that refer to \flushright or something.

For my title page I want to have Supervisor on the left, and Written By on the right at the bottom of the page. But when running the latter part, it is just relocated a bit more right and below the Supervisor part.

How do I force a minipage ( I guess? ) to the right side of the document, aligned with the text on the left?

Thanks in advance, code is below.

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
\flushleft
\textsc{Supervisor}

Prof. W. Name\\
\textit{University of XXX}
\end{minipage}

\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
\flushright
\textsc{Written by}

D Name\\
\textit{University of XXX}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are better suited using for example `\usepackage{multicol}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\flushleft
\textsc{Supervisor}

Prof. W. Name\\
\textit{University of XXX}

\flushright
\textsc{Written by}

D Name\\
\textit{University of XXX}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

which results in something like
[image]

Comment: Yes. However, I don't think `multicols` was born for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A way to obtain the alignment with `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\vfill
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lXr@{}}
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
\textsc{Supervisor}

Prof. W. Name\\
\textit{University of XXX}
\medskip
\end{minipage}
 & &
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
\flushright
\textsc{Written by}

D Name\\
\textit{University of XXX}%
\end{minipage}
\end{tabularx}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]